# Determine if one of the elements in an array is a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, element, typeof

Given an array of mixed types, "`getLongestWordOfMixedElements`" returns the longest string in the given array.

Notes:

- If the array is empty, it should return an empty string (`""`).
- If the array contains no strings; it should return an empty string.

How do I find out if the array contains a string or not, as in this code:

```
function getLongestWordOfMixedElements(arr) {

    if (arr.length === 0) return ""
    var max = 0
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(arr[i].length > max) max = arr[i]
    }
    return max
}

getLongestWordOfMixedElements([3, 'word', 5, 'up', 3, 1]);
```

Comment: Why did you tag [tag:typeof] and not use it?

Comment: [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)?

Comment: use **typeOf** operator to determine the type

Comment: I'm not sure how to use the typeof.  Would it if (!typeof arr[i] === "string") return "" ?

Answer (score 4):

You can *filter* the array for strings then use a *reduce* operation to find the longest one

```js
function getLongestWordOfMixedElements(arr) {
  return arr
    .filter(item => typeof item === 'string')
    .reduce((longest, str) => str.length > longest.length ? str : longest, '');
}

console.log(getLongestWordOfMixedElements([3, 'word', 5, 'up', 3, 1]));
```

---

Note that if any words are the same length, the earlier one in the array is returned.

---

Additionally, you could skip the *filter* and do the type check in the *reduce*...

```
return arr.reduce((longest, str) => {
  return typeof str === 'string' && str.length > longest.length ?
    str : longest;
}, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

You iterate over the element and check if its type is a string.
You can do so with `typeof`.

Let us say you would've a bunch of data and would not like to double your memory usage / or for the sake of the example in your code:

```js
function getLongestWordOfMixedElements(arr) {
    var max = "";

    if (arr.length) {
        arr.forEach(function (item) {
            if (typeof item === "string" && item.length > max) {
                max = item;
            }
        });
    }

    return max;
}


console.log(getLongestWordOfMixedElements([3, 'word', 5, 'up', 3, 1, {foo:4}]));
```

In your code you would change it this way:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var item = arr[i];

    if (typeof item === "string" && item.length > max) {
        max = arr[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well here's my version of it...

```
function getLongestWordOfMixedElements(arr) {
  let result = '';

  if (arr.length) {
    for(i in arr) {
      const value = arr[i];

      if (value && typeof value === 'string' && value.length > result.length) {
        result = value;
      }
    }
  }

  return result;
}


getLongestWordOfMixedElements([333333, 'word', 5, 'up', 3, 1]);
```

Comment: [Why is using “for…in” with array iteration a bad idea?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1529630)

Comment: I don't really see those as valid reasons. It's like if you make sloppy code, the for in loop is going to break.

Comment: Iterating enumerable inherited properties is not the main problem. The main problem is that iteration order is not well-defined, so in case there are multiple string values with the same length you can get inconsistent results